# Good book/resource recommendation for HTML5 mobile game development?

Tags: html5, mobile, books

**The problem**: I am taking an existing, 5 year old, html based MMORTS game and "HTML5-ing" it, "AJAX-ing" it and most importantly, optimizing for mobile devices like iPhone, android etc. For these devices, the application will be packaged as a downloadable app that is a wrapper for a browser which actually shows the game..

**The Question**
Looking for a good book, or books, or in-depth articles that would help me learn:

1. what tools I have in iOS, andriod applications for optimizing an html based game. things like caching of images, etc
2. what kind of connectivity, or interactivity I can expect between the html/javascript pages and the wrapper - can I play sounds in the wrapper by triggering them from javascript? etc
3. tip and tricks to optimize html/html5 & Javascript application to run well on mobile devices
4. ETC :)

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

I've not read or purchased it but this book (and the Impact framework) seem to be getting some positive feedback.

Introducing HTML5 Game Development - By Jesse Freeman
http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022633.do

Comment: It looks good enuf but it uses impactJS which is a commercial js library...

Answer (score 1):

I will share some of my findings if anyone is interested:

HTML5 mobile app development video - great intro to general html5 mobile dev. Basic but good start
http://my.safaribooksonline.com/video/web-development/mobile/9781449397388